# Load PartialView Result on JQuery change with data in Controller

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to fill the #Result with different partials. The #ViewSelector is a Select, which can be used to run an action on option change in the #ViewSelector.

Here the Code:

```
    $("#ViewSelector").change(function () {
        $('#Results').load('@Html.Action("SwitchMethodWhichSelectTheRightPartialAndFillsItWithCorrectData", new { justavar = "", viewID = "testingview"})');
    });

<div id="Results"></div>
```

Guys...The whole PartialView loads into the Javascript:

```
$("#ViewSelector").change(function () {
 $(s.innerHTML).load.('<!-- This is the Code of the Partial View -->
    <table>
       <tr>
            <!-- The Full  -->
       </tr>
    </table>');
```

How to Load the Content into the div #Results? In the #Results div there already exists a @Html.Action Call which calls a method in the Controller. Thats why I put the other View in other PartialView.

Comment: Should be `$('#Results').load('@Url.Action(`

Comment: @freedomn-m This is what it does:

$('#Results').load.('/Home/SwitchMethod?viewID=testingview');

Comment: correct, it will then load the partial when the jquery runs

Comment: @freedomn-m Thats true, but it should not load the partialview directly. It should load the method in the controller which returns the correct partialview with its data on reacting through ViewID. The ViewID already is set now so it gets the value of the html select options.

Comment: There's nothing in your *question* that states the action should be called with **different parameters**.  There's nothing in your code samples that shows setting the ViewID from the html select options.  The question stated is *"How to Load the content into the div #Results?"* which you do by using `$('#Results').load('url')`.  Your issue was, *as described*, that the `load()` was putting the view in, not the url.  I showed how to put the url in and you've confirmed this has worked.

Comment: Take out the viewID from the server-side code and add it via js in client-side code so it sends the parameter based on the `select`.  `$("#ViewSelector").change(function () { var id = $(this).val(); $('#Results').load('@Html.Action("SwitchMethodWhichSelectTheRightPartialAndFillsItWithCorrectData")' + "?viewID=" + id); });`